# magento validation related problem

Tags: validation, magento

can any one tell me where or in which file(path of that file I need to make change for edit validation class like **input-text required-entry** in magneto..

**I required this because->**
this validation is not working if there is default value in text box where this class is applied..
 like .. in my form name filed name has two text box in which default value is first and last respectively .. so the main problem is arise when user does not enter any text in these fields...and do submit and the validation class is get failed because its not any showing error message

Thanks for any help or suggestion

Richa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find that file at `/js/prototype/validation.js` note this is under the main root of the install, not in the skin js folders.